# Missing /dev/xconsole causes rsyslog to stop as well as all other services

Tags: 10.04, rsyslog

I'm running Ubuntu-10.04.04LTS in Hyper-V environments. I found that SSH, HTTP or any other service else stopped because the `rsyslog` daemon had died with the message `unable to find the /dev/xconsole file`.

I fixed it temporarily with the following.

```
FILE=/dev/xconsole
if [ -e $FILE ]; then
     echo "$FILE exists Carry on!"
else
     mknod -m 640 /dev/xconsole c 1 3
     chown syslog:adm /dev/xconsole
     echo "Created $FILE."
fi
```

The problem is that I can not get `rsyslog` daemon to process these 8 lines when I restart the daemon.

Also restarting the daemon removes the `/dev/xconsole` file and we are back to all service stopped. In addressing this problem I have inserted the `if`--`fi` lines after the start and restart conditions in the `rsyslog` script. The problem is I do not get an `echo` to `stdio`. Does someone have an idea on how to make the `rsyslog` report to `stdio` when it creates the `/dev/xconsole` device?

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem about syslog not being written.

Answer (score 23):

The reason this exists is because Ubuntu Server 12.04 incorrectly assumes you have **xterminal** installed.  It may be a hang over from their desktop OS where it does perhaps exist by default.

Anyway, best thing to do is simply comment it out of `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` as follows:

```
# daemon.*;mail.*;\
#        news.err;\
#        *.=debug;*.=info;\
#        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

And viola, no more error.

BTW. I doubt that was causing it to die though.

Comment: The same happened to me with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.