# /var/log/syslog empty

Tags: 12.10, syslog

Apparently my logs stopped working around Apr 10, as the current `/var/log/syslog` is empty, and `/var/log/syslog.1` has the following for its last entries:

```
Apr 10 20:25:01 li243-206 CRON[2883]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr 10 20:27:16 li243-206 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Apr 10 20:27:16 li243-206 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="2320" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

I tried writing to it with `logger "hello world"`, but nothing show up. `rsyslog` is indeed running, if I check with `ps`.

So I found this [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249490/rsyslogd-stopped-writing-to-var-log-syslog-two-days-ago), which led me to discover that `/dev/xconsole` was missing. I created it, rebooted, but still no joy.

How can I get syslog to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it to work by changing ownership from `messagebus.adm` to `syslog.adm`, and then restarting rsyslog.

Kind of disturbing that this broke silently. Given this experience I am not terribly confident that the other log files are owned properly.  Here's what I have currently:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root         0 May  1 06:31 alternatives.log
drwxr-x--- 2 root       adm       4096 Jun  9 06:46 apache2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root      4096 Jun  1 06:48 apt
-rw-r----- 1 messagebus adm          0 Oct 22  2012 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 root       adm          0 Oct 22  2012 boot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root         0 Oct 22  2012 boot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root         0 Oct 22  2012 bootstrap.log
-rw-rw---- 1 root       utmp      2688 Jun  6 10:31 btmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root      4096 Oct 18  2012 ConsoleKit
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root      4096 Oct 16  2012 dist-upgrade
-rw-r----- 1 root       adm      11669 Jun  6 13:16 dmesg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root     24494 Jun  6 11:30 dpkg.log
-rw-r----- 1 root       adm        117 Jun  9 06:46 fail2ban.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root     24024 Apr 11 10:36 faillog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root      1202 Apr 10 19:13 fontconfig.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root      4096 Oct 18  2012 fsck
drwxr-xr-x 3 root       root      4096 Oct 18  2012 installer
-rw-r----- 1 messagebus adm          0 Oct 22  2012 kern.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 syslog     root      4096 Oct 18  2012 landscape
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root       utmp    292292 Jun  9 10:38 lastlog
-rw-r----- 1 messagebus adm          0 Oct 22  2012 mail.err
-rw-r----- 1 messagebus adm          0 Oct 22  2012 mail.log
drwxr-s--- 2 mysql      adm       4096 Jun  9 06:46 mysql
-rw-r----- 1 mysql      adm          0 Apr 29 07:48 mysql.err
-rw-r----- 1 mysql      adm          0 Jun  9 06:46 mysql.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root      4096 Oct 18  2012 news
drwxr-xr-x 2 ntp        ntp       4096 Aug 20  2012 ntpstats
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody     nogroup   4096 Apr 10 23:00 passenger-analytics
-rw-r----- 1 syslog     adm       3538 Jun  9 11:10 syslog
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root      4096 May 24  2012 sysstat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root    285653 Jun  6 13:15 udev
-rw-r----- 1 messagebus adm          0 Oct 22  2012 ufw.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root      4096 Jun  8 06:29 upstart
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root       utmp     44928 Jun  9 10:38 wtmp
```

Does this look correct?

Edit: related discussion [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1059854).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Caffeine Coma's](https://askubuntu.com/users/165013/caffeine-coma) answer, Please try this command:

```
sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log/syslog
```

Then restart services or restart your system(reboot).

Comment: restart of services was not needed on Ubuntu 12

Answer (score -2):

same problem here /var/log/syslog empty (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS)
What worked for me was changing the rights to 777 and testing thus :

```
chmod 777 syslog
logger "hello world"
```

and you can follow it working with :

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: You should never chmod 777 a file. The problem is most likely an ownership issue.